# how to find a reference datatype

Tags: c#

public static void Refer(ref int a,ref  int b)
                                                                                                   in this how do i find that these variables are reference variable programatically ..how do i find their type

Comment: Are you asking if there is a way to determine if a and b are passed by reference into the method, or if a and b are reference types (as opposed to value types)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to know via reflection that the method parameters are by-ref?

You use [`MethodBase.GetParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx) to get the parameters for the method, and then [`ParameterInfo.ParameterType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.parameterinfo.parametertype.aspx) to find the type of the parameter and [`Type.IsByRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isbyref.aspx) to check whether or not it's passed by reference.

Here's a quick example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

public class Test
{
    public static void Refer(ref int a,ref int b)
    {
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Refer");
        ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();
        foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is ref? {1}",
                              parameter.Name,
                              parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef);
        }
    }
}
```

You can't do this in a "strong" way for a variable using `a.GetType()` or `typeof(a)` etc. `GetType()` finds the type of the *value* of `a`, which is just an `int`.

Comment: also see this question answered by Jon Skeet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738277/net-reflection-how-to-get-real-type-from-out-parameterinfo on how to 'de-reference' ParameterType to get the Type  you can use with Type.IsAssignableFrom

Answer (score 1):

Since C# is strongly typed, you can use any `int` methods safely since `a` and `b` have to be `ints`. But if you need the `Type` during runtime, use the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx) operator.

```
Type intType = typeof(a);
```

Comment: Does typeof work on variables?  I was thinking it only worked on type names.  I think for variables you have to use a.GetType()

Answer (score 0):

You have the [IsByRef](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isbyref.aspx) property on the parameterInfo.ParameterType.

```
MethodInfo refer = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("Refer");
ParameterInfo [] parameters = refer.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo parameter in parameters)
{
        Console.WriteLine("Parameter: {0}, Type: {1}, ByRef: {2}", parameter.Name,
        parameter.ParameterType.Name,
        parameter.ParameterType.IsByRef);
}
```