# How to find a parameter type by typeParameterInfo in case of "out" declaration.

Tags: c#, reflection

I have p as ParameterInfo

```
p.ParameterType.GetTypeInfo()
```

returns

> {Name = "Decimal&" FullName =
>   "**System.Decimal&**"}    System.Reflection.TypeInfo {**System.RuntimeType**}

in real world this is an `out double` parameter of a method.

What would be the best way to find a mach to the `double` nature of the parameter? Is the name comparison approach is only the way it will work???

Comment: I typed your question into [Google](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHLW_enAU510AU510&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=get%20underlying%20type%20of%20out&safe=off) and found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/738277/242520)

Comment: “FullName = "System.Decimal&" … in real world this is an `out double` parameter” Something doesn't add up here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Type type = p.ParameterType;
if(type.IsByRef)
{
    Type actualType = type.GetElementType();
    // ...
}
else
{
    // ...
}
```

The above is also useful for arrays (with `type.IsArray`, note). For `Nullable<T>`, you can use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(...)`.

On the topic of `IsByRef`: note that `out` is actually just `ref` with special rules about definite assignment; at the IL level, only `ref` really exists (`out` is just compiler candy).