# MethodInfo get the event from the list found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add to a list of strings all the names of the public methods of a specific class.

I'm a good point but for some reason, if the class has an event, it's added as well to the list.

How can I get the namespace of the field found (of System.Action) without using cheap tricks?

```
public List<string> methodsList = new List<string>();

private void UpdateDropdownList()
{
    methodsList.Clear();

    MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(WebcamScreenshootBehaviour).GetMethods();

    foreach (var method in methodInfos)
    {
        if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(WebcamScreenshootBehaviour) &&
            method.IsPublic &&
            method.ToString().Contains("System.Action") == false)   // Yuck!
        {
            methodsList.Add(method.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the WebcamScreenshootBehaviour class

```
 public class WebcamScreenshootBehaviour : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action OnScreenshootIsTaken;
    public static event Action OnScreenshootIsReset;

    // Somewhere else in this class: OnScreenshootIsTaken?.Invoke();
}
```

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dnjx.png)

Comment: is it just a field or actually an `event` ?

Comment: couldn't you already filter this by not getting `static` but only instance method?

Comment: I already thought that, unfortunately the problem is if I have a public static method, it's filtered as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that without comparing the strings. Just get the return type of the method and compare it with the type `System.Action`.

```
if (method.ReturnType == typeof(System.Action))
{
    // Do something if method is of type System.Action
}
```

Your if statement should look like this then:

```
if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(WebcamScreenshootBehaviour) &&
    method.IsPublic &&
    method.ReturnType != typeof(System.Action))
{
    methodsList.Add(method.Name);
}
```

---

After searching for a long time I think I finally found a solution. My code now looks like this. I am getting the underlying system type of the parameter and compare it to `System.Action`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738277/net-reflection-how-to-get-real-type-from-out-parameterinfo) question set me on the right track.

```
MethodInfo[] methodInfos = typeof(MethodSearch).GetMethods();

foreach (var method in methodInfos)
{
    var paramInfo = method.GetParameters();

    bool isOfTypeAction = true;

    if (paramInfo.Length > 0)
        isOfTypeAction = paramInfo[0].ParameterType.UnderlyingSystemType != typeof(System.Action);

    if (method.DeclaringType == typeof(MethodSearch) &&
        method.IsPublic &&
        !isOfTypeAction)
    {
        methodsList.Add(method.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, the return type is void, maybe because it's an Action and not a Func I believe. I updated my question with more details. Thanks.

Comment: System.Action returns no value (void). See: [What is System.Action?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/335953/what-is-systemaction.html)

Comment: Indeed, and because of that the filter does not work. If I use method.ReturnType != typeof(System.Action) it still return the action fields because is void and it doesn't understand that it's an Action (see the screenshot at the end of the answer)

Comment: @Matteo I updated my answer. I think I finally found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could additionally get the events and filter them out like e.g.

```
public List<string> methodsList = new List<string>();

private void UpdateDropdownList()
{
    var type = typeof(WebcamScreenshootBehaviour);

    var methodInfos = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
    var eventInfos = type.GetEvents(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

    methodsList = methodInfos 
                  // get only the names
                  .Select(method => method.Name)
                  // filter out if the name matches any of the event names
                  .Where(name => eventInfos.All(e => e.Name != name))
                  // then convert to list
                  .ToList();
}
```

if this is so much less `Yuck` is questionable I guess ;)